# Check integer values in TextBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two textboxes having integer values in both .Now i want to make condition and make if else condition and trying to check if user enters zero(0) in first textbox and some integer value in second textbox then add both and display it in third textbox i have tried using int.Parse but in vain.Can anyone explain me how to do this?

I want something like this:

```
if(txtPrevious.text==0 && txtTodaysTotal.text==somevalue)
{
  update txtCredit;
}
```

Comment: `"i have tried using int.Parse but in vain"`  Show us the code that you tried.  Explain what about that code wasn't working.  Did it not compile, did it error at runtime, did it not produce the correct result?  Explain *in detail* what the problem was.

Comment: textbox returns string but i am comparing it with integer that is the problem!

Comment: `if(txtPrevious.Text == "0" && ...)`

Comment: @user3262450 That in no way answers my questions.  When you post the solution that you said you tried that didn't work, and explain why it didn't work, then we'll be able to understand what the problem is, and can help you solve it.

Comment: @Jonesy That's *super* fragile.  according to that `"00"` isn't zero.  `"0.0"` isn't zero.  And then when you start comparing to other numbers you need to start worrying about different culture's decimal separator characters, thousands separators, etc.  It's *far* more effective to parse the strings to numbers first, and then do the comparisons as numbers.

Comment: you can use validation for numbers only?Then use int.Parse(txtprevious.Text) to add and compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to add zero to today's result, but here is an example of how to do it with TryParse:

```
        int prev, today;

        //first check that prev is an int
        if (int.TryParse(txtPrevious.text, out prev))
        {

            if (prev == 0 && int.TryParse(txtTodaysTotal.text, out today))
            {
                txtThree.Text = (prev + today).ToString();
            }
        }
```